# NuGet version rule with appended string in octopus deploy

Tags: nuget, versioning, octopus-deploy, semantic-versioning

I have a process that deploys a NuGet package and I would like to create different channels to deploy the package using different lifecycles based on the version. Ideally the version will look like the following:

x.x.x.x-NL

or

x.x.x.x-UK

i.e the packages will differ based on country.

Is there a way to specify a country code like this and have a version rule to only pick up the packages with a specific country code appended like this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, but it's likely that you'll have to hard code the country code into the regular expression.

[image]
[image]

[Octopus Deploy Channel Tags](http://docs.octopusdeploy.com/display/OD/Channels#Channels-tags)

Hope this helps.

Comment: That's great! Thanks. I was trying to do it using the version range and obviously it wasn't working. Lack of understanding on my part. Thank you for the help.